# How to set the property of sink pad of element in gstreamer?

Tags: c, gstreamer

How to set the property of sink pad in program 
for example:

```
sin_00::outWidth=1280 sin_00::outHeight=720 in this way pipeline was run using gst-launch-0.10 .....
```

And to set this property Ive used `gst_pad_set_property()` API but its not working 
it shows following error :

```
3_video_temp.c: In function 'main':
3_video_temp.c:551: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gst_pad_set_property'
/tmp/cc2zDbzt.o: In function `main':
/home/project/compWorkspace/Edubeam/3_video_temp.c:551: undefined reference to `gst_pad_set_property'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Please tell how to set that value as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If the pads have properties (like the pads in videomixer has), you just use g_object_set like you would with any property, so something like:

```
g_object_set (pad, "width", 1280, NULL);
```

Comment: I think this might work for bin but not at pad level. How gstreamer will know which pad are you refering to ?

Comment: You can get the pointer to the pad using

`GstPad * pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(element, "sink");`

Where 'element' is the GstElement you're concerned with

Answer (score 1):

Most pads don't have properties. width and height are usually negotiated via caps that are set on buffers and pads.

Answer (score 0):

What version of GStreamer do you have installed on your system? Quickly check using:

```
gst-inspect --version
```

Where did you find a doc or example for gst_pad_set_property()? I just searched for gst_pad_set_property in /usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/* on my Linux development system and came up empty-handed. But when I search through the latest source snapshot for GStreamer, the function appears. This leads me to believe you might be looking at docs or examples for an in-development version of GStreamer that has new convenience APIs not seen in earlier versions (I have run into similar problems on occasion).

Exactly what property are you trying to set on the sink pad?