# How to modify videomixer sink pad alpha value dynamically

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I want to take a video file and overlay subtitles that fade in and fade out.

I'm just beginning to learn how to work with Gstreamer.

So far, I've managed to put together a pipeline that composits a subtitle stream drawn by the *textrender* element onto an original video stream with the *videomixer* element.  Unfortunately, textrender, and its sister element *textoverlay* do not have a fade-in/fade-out feature.

The videomixer sink pad does have an alpha property.  For now, I have set the alpha value of the pad named videomixer.sink_1 to 1.0.  Here is the command-line version of that pipeline:

```
#!/bin/bash

gst-launch-1.0 \
    filesrc location=sample_videos/my-video.mp4 ! decodebin ! mixer.sink_0 \
    filesrc location=subtitles.srt ! subparse ! textrender !  mixer.sink_1 \
    videomixer name=mixer sink_0::zorder=2 sink_1::zorder=3 sink_1::ypos=-25 sink_1::alpha=1 \
        ! video/x-raw, height=540 \
        ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I am looking for a way to dynamically modify that alpha value over time so that I can make the subtitle component fade in and out at the appropriate times.  (I will parse the SRT file separately to determine when fades begin and end.)

I am studying the GstBin C API (my actual code is in Python).  I think after I create the pipeline with Gst.parse_launch(), I can grab any named element with gst_get_bin_by_name(), then use that value to access the pad "sink_1".

Once I've gotten that far, will I be able to modify that alpha value dynamically from an event handler that receives timer events?  Will the videomixer element respond instantly to changes in that pad's property?  Has anyone else done this?

I found a partial answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331845/270511 but they don't tell me if this will work after the pipeline is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work.  You can read about it in this post: https://westside-consulting.blogspot.com/2017/03/getting-to-know-gstreamer-part-4.html

Comment: Enjoyed the blog post, will definitely use it as a reference for future gstreamer projects

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it will work**.

The videomixer pads respond dynamically to changes; I have done this with both the alpha and position properties. The pad properties can be changed using

```
    g_object_set (mix_sink_pad, "alpha", 0.5, NULL);
```

I am using C, but your python strategy for accessing the bin and pad sound correct. My gstreamer code responds based on inputs from a udp socket, but timer events will work perfectly fine. For example, if you wanted to change the alpha value every 100ms, you could do something like this

```
    g_timeout_add_seconds (100, alpha_changer_cb, loop);
```

You can then change the alpha property using g_object_set in the callback; it will update dynamically and looks very smooth.

Comment: That's fantastic.  Thank you.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this without callbacks. Each visitor to the site will view the same video and soundtrack, but should see custom subtitles unique to that visitor. However, the timing of the subtitles never varies so the fade effects should always happen in the same places.  Might there be a way to accomplish this with a third track that controls the opaqueness of the subtitles without affecting the original video (bottom layer)?  Should I start a new question?

Comment: I am no expert, but there are definitely more efficient ways to do this without callbacks; most of my gstreamer experience is with live video so I am not too familiar with timed events. A third track sounds like the right idea and you can certainly control a third track without affecting the original layer. You might be familiar with it already, but the gstreamer application manual is extremely useful and has some very good examples: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/manual.pdf      Maybe check out this project as well https://github.com/voc/voctomix

Comment: how did you get mix_sink_pad here?  g_object_set (mix_sink_pad, "alpha", 0.5, NULL);